# pageblockTable spanning multiple section Columns?

Tags: visualforce

So I'm trying to make THIS *see pic*, into One single table, so it's easier for my jQuery plug-in that Sorts (tableSorter).

[image]

(if you can't see - 3 column pageblock Section, 3 tables with nicely aligned outputlabels)

I've played with lots of things, and so far I haven't been able to google anything that points me in the right direction.    Here is my somewhat Redacted code.  How do I get this table to span all 3 columns, instead of just one?

```
 <apex:pageBlockSection id="clientListSearchResults" title="Search Results" rendered="{!wrapClient.size >0}" columns="3">

       <apex:outputlabel />
       <apex:outputLabel value="X"/>
       <apex:outputLabel value="Y"/>

       <apex:pageblocktable value ="{!X}" var="c" id="Y" styleclass="tablesorter">
           <apex:column value="{!c.X}" headervalue="Y" />
           <apex:column value="{!c.X}" headervalue="Y" />
           <apex:column value="{!c.X}" headervalue = "Y/>
           <apex:column value="{!c.X}" headervalue = "Y"/>
           <apex:column value="{!c.X}" headervalue = "Y"/>
           <apex:column value="{!c.X}" Headervalue = "Y"/>
           <apex:column value="{!c.X}" headervalue="Y" />
           <apex:column value="{!c.X}" headervalue = "Y"/>
           <apex:column value="{!c.X}" headervalue = "Y"/>
           <apex:column value="{!c.X}" headervalue = "Y"/>
           <apex:column value="{!c.X}" headervalue = "Y"/>
       </apex:pageblocktable>

   </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

EDIT:  fixed for clarity!

Answer (score 1):

The way you've redacted this makes it difficult to understand exactly what you're trying to do. But I think the answer will lie somewhere in the [wrapper class pattern](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Wrapper_Class). So instead of there being three separate lists of data, there is one list...and thus one single table.

So essentially you have an apex class with a bunch of properties. It can be standalone, or an inner class.

```
public class MyWrapper {

  public String wrapperName {get;set;}
  public Integer measure1 {get;set;}
  public Integer measure2 {get;set;}
  public Integer measure3 {get;set;}
  public Integer measure4 {get;set;}
  public Integer measure5 {get;set;}
  public Integer measure6 {get;set;}
  public Integer measure7 {get;set;}

}
```

You can then martial together data into lists of that class.

```
public List<MyWrapper> someData {get;set;}
```

Then you need to get the data into it. Let's say the "Name" is from an account.

```
someData = new List<MyWrapper>();

for (Account a : aListOfAccounts) {

  MyWrapper item = new MyWrapper();
  item.wrapperName = a.Name;
  item.measure1 = a.SomeCustomField__c;
  item.measure2 = mapOfSomeStuff.get(a.Id).SomeMeasureField__c;
  item.measure3 = mapOfSomeOtherStuff.get(a.Id).SomeOtherMeasureField__c;
  ...and so on...

}
```

Then you have *one* page block table to work with:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!someData}" var="item">
  <apex:column value="{!item.wrapperName}"/>
  <apex:column value="{!item.measure1}"/>
  ...and so on...
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Comment: OK great, thanks for that.  I should have been way more clear, my apologies!  If pageblockSection has 3 columns... how do I span that PageblockTable across all 3 columns?

Comment: @RC82 - Make a section for the table with a column out of 1 and a section for the rest with a column count of 3.